# Resources$NotFoundException - Resource ID #<address>

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, imagebutton, resourcesnotfoundexception

I am facing a lot of issue regarding Resoures$NotFoundException with many different device. I am unable to replicate this issue with my Samsung A50 (Android v11, One UI v3.1) and Nexus 5 (Android v6.0.1) devices. After I am using App Bundle this problem raises every day and even return to upload as APK file also have same issue. So I am not sure for which reason app is crashing.

Below is the trace report

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class ImageButton

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class ImageButton

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable (missing name) with resource ID #0x7f0800ad

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f0800ad
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourceName(ResourcesImpl.java:253)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:760)
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:630)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:886)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
       at android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.getDrawable(XResources.java:1363)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:188)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:86)
       at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:82)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:3)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:3)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:15)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:15)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:15)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:15)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:189)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at com.pn.namewallpaper.databinding.BsFontColorStyleBinding.bind(BsFontColorStyleBinding.java:4)
       at com.pn.namewallpaper.databinding.BsFontColorStyleBinding.inflate(BsFontColorStyleBinding.java:4)
       at com.pn.namewallpaper.fragments.FontColorStyle2BSDialog.Q(FontColorStyle2BSDialog.java:6)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.b0(Fragment.java:20)
       at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.performCreateView(DialogFragment.java)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:223)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:154)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1069)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:91)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:74)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:3)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

My xml layout file code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_spinner">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spColorStyle"
                style="@style/spinner"
                android:contentDescription="@string/style" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAngle"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle.Circle"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/rotate"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_angle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnRandom"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle.BottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/random" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSame"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle.BottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="@string/same" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have attached crash report from Firebase Crashlytics

[image: Crash Report]

Thanks
Please help me how can I fix this issue.

Comment: This ic_arrow_angle in any specific directory?

Comment: @sasikumar its in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi

Answer (score 1):

some device not matched above directory  **drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi** that's what crash happened.

Put default image in the directory **drawable**. if anything matched it will take from the drawable. App wont crash

Comment: the system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's dpi. If you don't provide a density-specific resource for that density, the system locates the next-best match and scales it to fit the screen.

Comment: but your case its not taken next-best match. so that i told put default image in drawable

Answer (score 1):

This problem often occurs due to the missing resource in drawable but available in specific drawable folders like *drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi*. To solve the issue put the specific resource in main drawable folder too.
To find the which resource is creating the issue you can find that resource from provided id, in this case id is **#0x7f0800ad**.
To find name from of resource form id in android studio click on and select your apk.

```
Build -> Analyze Apk -> Select apk
```

**Below screen will open to you**

[image]

1. Click on **resources.arsc**
2. Click on specific resource type which is casing the issue in this case its
   drawable.
3. You will find all the resource with ids available in your apk. from here you can search for resource with provided id and add the specific resource in your main drawable folder too.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, I have drawable vector icon along with png files in drawable-anydpi folder. I deleted all the vectors icon and just provide png icons only. Now no more crash report generated related to this issue.